# Exclude Temporary Storage (D:) from KQL QUERY

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have a KQL query from disk logs from Azure Log Insights. Please let me know how to exclude a particular drive like D: or any temporary storage from this query.

```
InsightsMetrics
  | where Name == "FreeSpaceMB"
  | extend Tags = parse_json(Tags)
  | extend mountId = tostring(Tags["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
          ,diskSizeMB = toreal(Tags["vm.azm.ms/diskSizeMB"])
  | project-rename FreeSpaceMB = Val
  | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, diskSizeMB, FreeSpaceMB) by Computer, mountId
           ,FreeSpacePercentage = round(FreeSpaceMB / diskSizeMB * 100, 1)
  | extend diskSizeGB = round(diskSizeMB / 1024, 1)
          ,FreeSpaceGB = round(FreeSpaceMB / 1024, 1)
  | project TimeGenerated, Computer, mountId, diskSizeGB, FreeSpaceGB, FreeSpacePercentage
  | order by Computer asc, mountId asc
```

Comment: `| where mountId != "D:"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a where statement

```
| where mountId != "D:"
```

So in your query it will be

```
InsightsMetrics
  | where Name == "FreeSpaceMB"
  | extend Tags = parse_json(Tags)
  | extend mountId = tostring(Tags["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
          ,diskSizeMB = toreal(Tags["vm.azm.ms/diskSizeMB"])
  | where mountId != "D:"
  | project-rename FreeSpaceMB = Val
  | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, diskSizeMB, FreeSpaceMB) by Computer, mountId
           ,FreeSpacePercentage = round(FreeSpaceMB / diskSizeMB * 100, 1)
  | extend diskSizeGB = round(diskSizeMB / 1024, 1)
          ,FreeSpaceGB = round(FreeSpaceMB / 1024, 1)
  | project TimeGenerated, Computer, mountId, diskSizeGB, FreeSpaceGB, FreeSpacePercentage
  | order by Computer asc, mountId asc
```

And if you wanted to exclude multiple drives from the query, you can use the !in operator, will look like below

```
InsightsMetrics
  | where Name == "FreeSpaceMB"
  | extend Tags = parse_json(Tags)
  | extend mountId = tostring(Tags["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
          ,diskSizeMB = toreal(Tags["vm.azm.ms/diskSizeMB"])
  | where mountId !in ("D:", "E:")
  | project-rename FreeSpaceMB = Val
  | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, diskSizeMB, FreeSpaceMB) by Computer, mountId
           ,FreeSpacePercentage = round(FreeSpaceMB / diskSizeMB * 100, 1)
  | extend diskSizeGB = round(diskSizeMB / 1024, 1)
          ,FreeSpaceGB = round(FreeSpaceMB / 1024, 1)
  | project TimeGenerated, Computer, mountId, diskSizeGB, FreeSpaceGB, FreeSpacePercentage
  | order by Computer asc, mountId asc
```